# How do I remove "language support" entry, which is appearing twice under applications menu in Ubuntu Budgie 20.04?

Tags: .desktop, vim, budgie

I am pretty new to the OS. I just discovered that there are 2 entries being displayed for "language support" under applications.
[image: language_support]

What I have tried so far:

1. navigated to `/usr/share/applications`
   looked for the corresponding `.desktop` file. I opened the file in VIM. Made sure that the pointers were mapped correctly using the below command.

   ```
   xprop | grep WM_CLASS
   ```
2. Some URLs navigated for resolution

   - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74405/duplicate-instances-within-gnome-menu
   - https://jaisejames.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/to-remove-duplicate-icons-from-applications-menu-in-activities-of-gnome-3-3-2-fedora-15-16/

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, please do not add "SOLVED" to the title. Correct way to do it is by ["accepting" the most helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it). If it is your self-answer you would have to wait for 2 days before you would be able to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to find a solution. Found the entry for language support. Opened the file in VIM and added

```
NoDisplay=true
```

That seems to have fixed it.